# Proof about bounded sequence

Tags: calculus

Proof if $(a_{n+1}-a_n)$ is bounded sequence, then the sequence  $\frac{{a_n}}{n^2}$ lim is $0$.

I could see that it is valid for $1,2,3,4....\ (a_n=n)$ then the sequence bounded in 1 and $\frac{{a_n}}{n^2}$ is $\frac{1}{n}$ and the lim is 0 but, how could I proof it in general ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let $k$ be a bound on $|a_{n+1}-a_n|$. Then note that we have
$$
|a_n|\leq |a_0| + nk
$$

Comment: Thanks Arthur !